# "print_control_identifiers()" function doesn't get any info from a ComboBox on Dolphin Gamecube Emulator

Tags: python-2.7, pywinauto

I am using Dolphin 5.0-6711 gcb emulator which is one of the old versions and it use Qt5. I am trying to open "File->Tools->Start Netplay..." and starting a host from this new opened window named "Dolphin NetPlay Setup". I can edit `Port`, `Nickname` and select a game from `ListBox`. But i cannot select any items from "Connection Type" `ComboBox` which has `Direct Connection` and `Treversal Server` options. When I use `print_control_identifiers()` for "Dolphin NetPlay Setup" window,  I could not see any `ComboBox` items. This is my output from `print_control_identifiers()` :

```
Dialog - 'Dolphin NetPlay Setup'    (L627, T351, R1277, B854)
[u'Dolphin NetPlay Setup', u'Dialog', u'Dolphin NetPlay SetupDialog']
child_window(title="Dolphin NetPlay Setup", control_type="Window")
   |
   | Pane - 'panel'    (L636, T389, R1268, B845)
   | ['Pane', u'panelPane0', u'panelPane1', u'panel', u'panelPane', 
u'panel0', u'panel1', u'Pane1', u'Pane0']
   | child_window(title="panel", auto_id="-31967", control_type="Pane")
   |    |
   |    | Static - 'Connection Type:'    (L642, T398, R756, B419)
   |    | [u'Connection Type:Static', u'Connection Type:1', u'Connection 
Type:0', u'Static', u'Connection Type:Static1', u'Connection Type:Static0', 
u'Static1', u'Static0', u'Connection Type:']
   |    | child_window(title="Connection Type:", auto_id="-31966", 
control_type="Text")
   |    |
   |    | ComboBox - 'Connection Type:'    (L762, T395, R950, B423)
   |    | [u'Connection Type:ComboBox', u'Connection Type:2', 'ComboBox']
   |    | child_window(title="Connection Type:", auto_id="-31965", 
control_type="ComboBox")
   |    |    |
   |    |    | Static - 'Connection Type:'    (L3, T3, R164, B25)
   |    |    | [u'Connection Type:3', u'Connection Type:Static2', u'Static2']
   |    |    | child_window(title="Connection Type:", control_type="Text")
   |    |    |
   |    |    | Button - 'Open'    (L930, T396, R949, B422)
   |    |    | [u'OpenButton', u'Button1', u'Button0', u'Open', 'Button']
   |    |    | child_window(title="Open", auto_id="DropDown", control_type="Button")
   |    |
   |    | Static - 'Nickname:'    (L642, T432, R711, B453)
   |    | [u'Nickname:', u'Nickname:Static', u'Static3']
   |    | child_window(title="Nickname:", auto_id="-31963", control_type="Text")
   |    |
   |    | Edit - 'Nickname:'    (L762, T429, R950, B457)
   |    | [u'', u'0', u'Edit1', u'Nickname:Edit', u'1', 'Edit', u'Edit0']
   |    | child_window(title="Nickname:", auto_id="-31962", control_type="Edit")
   |    |
   |    | Button - 'Quit'    (L1162, T804, R1262, B839)
   |    | ['Button2', u'Quit', u'QuitButton']
   |    | child_window(title="Quit", auto_id="-31960", control_type="Button")
   |    |
   |    | TabControl - ''    (L642, T490, R1262, B798)
   |    | [u'2', u'TabControlHost', u'TabControlConnect', u'TabControl']
   |    | child_window(auto_id="-31959", control_type="Tab")
   |    |    |
   |    |    | Pane - 'panel'    (L646, T519, R1258, B794)
   |    |    | [u'panelPane2', u'panel2', 'Pane2']
   |    |    | child_window(title="panel", auto_id="-31957", control_type="Pane")
   |    |    |    |
   |    |    |    | Static - 'Port:'    (L652, T528, R682, B549)
   |    |    |    | [u'Port:', u'Port:Static', u'Static4']
   |    |    |    | child_window(title="Port:", auto_id="-31949", control_type="Text")
   |    |    |    |
   |    |    |    | Edit - 'Port:'    (L688, T525, R823, B553)
   |    |    |    | [u'3', u'Port:Edit', 'Edit2']
   |    |    |    | child_window(title="Port:", auto_id="-31948", control_type="Edit")
   |    |    |    |
   |    |    |    | Button - 'Host'    (L1152, T753, R1252, B788)
   |    |    |    | [u'Host1', u'Host0', u'Host', 'Button3', u'HostButton']
   |    |    |    | child_window(title="Host", auto_id="-31945", control_type="Button")
   |    |    |    |
   |    |    |    | ListBox - ''    (L652, T559, R1252, B747)
   |    |    |    | [u'4', u'ListBox']
   |    |    |    | child_window(auto_id="-31944", control_type="List")
   |    |    |    |    |
   |    |    |    |    | ListItem - 'CAPCOM VS. SNK 2 EO (GEOE08)'    (L654, T561, R1250, B581)
   |    |    |    |    | [u'ListItem', u'CAPCOM VS. SNK 2 EO (GEOE08)', u'CAPCOM VS. SNK 2 EO (GEOE08)ListItem']
   |    |    |    |    | child_window(title="CAPCOM VS. SNK 2 EO (GEOE08)", control_type="ListItem")
   |    |    |    |
   |    |    |    | CheckBox - 'Forward Port (UPnP)'    (L829, T529, R991, B549)
   |    |    |    | ['CheckBox', u'Forward Port (UPnP)', u'Forward Port (UPnP)CheckBox']
   |    |    |    | child_window(title="Forward Port (UPnP)", auto_id="-31943", control_type="CheckBox")
   |    |    |
   |    |    | TabItem - 'Connect'    (L644, T492, R710, B517)
   |    |    | [u'ConnectTabItem', 'TabItem', u'Connect', u'TabItem0', u'TabItem1']
   |    |    | child_window(title="Connect", control_type="TabItem")
   |    |    |
   |    |    | TabItem - 'Host'    (L710, T492, R770, B517)
   |    |    | [u'Host2', 'TabItem2', u'HostTabItem']
   |    |    | child_window(title="Host", control_type="TabItem")
   |
   | TitleBar - ''    (L656, T354, R1268, B389)
   | ['TitleBar', u'5']
   |    |
   |    | Menu - 'System'    (L636, T360, R664, B388)
   |    | [u'System0', u'System1', u'System', u'Menu', u'SystemMenu']
   |    | child_window(title="System", auto_id="MenuBar", control_type="MenuBar")
   |    |    |
   |    |    | MenuItem - 'System'    (L636, T360, R664, B388)
   |    |    | [u'System2', u'MenuItem', u'SystemMenuItem']
   |    |    | child_window(title="System", control_type="MenuItem")
   |    |
   |    | Button - 'Minimize'    (L1090, T352, R1150, B389)
   |    | ['Button4', u'Minimize', u'MinimizeButton']
   |    | child_window(title="Minimize", control_type="Button")
   |    |
   |    | Button - 'Maximize'    (L1150, T352, R1209, B389)
   |    | ['Button5', u'MaximizeButton', u'Maximize']
   |    | child_window(title="Maximize", control_type="Button")
   |    |
   |    | Button - 'Close'    (L1209, T352, R1269, B389)
   |    | ['Button6', u'CloseButton', u'Close']
   |    | child_window(title="Close", control_type="Button")
```

This is my codes for starting a host without selecting any ComboBox items:

```
from pywinauto.application import Application


app = Application(backend="uia")
app.start(r"./Dolphin-x64/Dolphin.exe")
dlg = app["Dolphin"]
dlg.menu_select("Tools->Start NetP")
netplay = app["Dolphin NetPlay Setup"]
netplay.print_control_identifiers()
netplay.Pane.Edit.set_text(username)
netplay.Pane.TabControl.select("Host")
netplay.Pane.TabControl.Pane.Edit.set_text("9999")               
netplay.Pane.TabControl.Pane.ListBox.child_window(title="CAPCOM VS. SNK 2 EO (GEOE08)", control_type="ListItem").select()
netplay.Pane.TabControl.Pane.Button.click()
```

I want to select the first "Direct Connection" option from the `ComboBox`. I tried `select("Direct Connection")` and `select(0)` but I can't decide which one i should use for navigation.

I even cannot get any info from `print_control_identifiers()` for main window in the lastest version of Dolphin which is why i am try to this old version.

EDIT:

I found out there was a secret button in that ComboBox. If I click `netplay.Pane.ComboBox.Button.click()` that button a ListBox and a second secret close button appear inside the ComboBox according to `netplay.print_control_identifiers()` and even if I select "Direct Connection" item in the ListBox you should close that second secret close button to affect ComboBox change.

Comment: See the updated answer with the fix for the specific Dolphin version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is known problem for some combo boxes ([issue #532](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/issues/532)) fixed in master branch of pywinauto (not released yet, will be in 0.6.6 version soon). You can try the fix out by

```
pip uninstall pywinauto
pip install https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/archive/master.zip
```

Also I'm seeing their Qt toolbar has "detouched" children buttons that are visible in `Inspect.exe` by mouse hovering, but Toolbar doesn't list them as children. We're working on workaround that is relevant to MFC toolbar as well. This is tracked in [issue #413](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/issues/413).

---

EDIT1: The issue with the latest version of Dolphin looks very strange and probably it's an app side problem. `Inspect.exe` shows error for property `Children`:

```
Children:   [Error: calling getter for this property: hr=0xFFFFFFFF80004005 - Unspecified error]
```

But it can re-build the hierarchy for the main window children somehow. It's interesting and looks new to me. I'm willing to look into this issue deeper.

---

EDIT2: We've bypassed Qt5 issue by using RawViewWalker object instead of FindAll() function in MS UI Automation API. If you want to participate in early testing of next major release (beta quality on Windows), you can try to install it this way:

```
pip uninstall -y pywinauto
pip install https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/archive/atspi.zip
```

Please note that some backward compatibility is broken, but all error messages should tell you what to replace in your code to make it working. If some error message is unclear, feel free to report a new issue on GitHub. Thanks!